# How to connect SQLAnywhere 11 server from a remote location

Tags: sybase, remote-access, sqlanywhere

Is there any way to connect SQLAnywhere 11 server from a remote location?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Do you want to connect a SQL Anywhere client to a remote SQL Anywhere server? Then use the connectivity options mentioned in the answers.
Or do you want to connect to a remote SQL Anywhere server from a local SQL Anywhere server (or vice versa)? Then setup a so called "remote server".

Answer (score 1):

Use the connectivity options that allowyou to specify host + port (like dbisql -host ... -port...)

Answer (score 1):

For version 11, you will need to add the LINKS parameter to your DSN or connection string. The documentation on the LINKS parameter for v11 is [here](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#1101/en/dbadmin_en11/links.html*d5e15070). If you are using SQL Anywhere v12 or later, take a look at the [HOST](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#1201/en/dbadmin/host-con-parm.html*d5e20027) parameter which is a little simpler.